# How to set the Sender and Recipient of Email using Odata Client in Dynamics?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, odata

I'm trying to add Sender and Recipient to Email using the activity party concept in Dynamics. I'm using Simple Odata Client. But I get the following error:

> message: "The 'Create' method does not support entities of type 'activityparty'."

***Code***:

```
parties = [];
var sender = {};
var recipient = {};
sender["partyid_systemuser@odata.bind"] = "/systemusers(37d4b5e8-f0c8-e911-a976-000d3a13cdfe)";
sender["participationtypemask"]= 1; 
recipient["partyid_systemuser@odata.bind"] = "/systemusers(37d4b5e8-f0c8-e911-a976-000d3a13cdfe)";
recipient["participationtypemask"]= 2; 
parties.push(sender);
parties.push(recipient);
entity["email_activity_parties"] = parties;
```

> Stacktrace: [image]

Comment: Can you provide the WHOLE code? The devil might be in the details.

Comment: Also, for reference, here's an article describing the process: https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/dynamics365enterprisecloudfronts/posts/creating-an-email-activity-in-ms-crm-through-webapi

Comment: Added the code @Shaamaan

Comment: I'm confused. The initial code you provided is clearly JS. Now you have added C# code. Just... slow down. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, if C# is used, those are some strange queries and executions. Are you using the official SDK?

Comment: The initial code is what I referred to, I'm trying to access the dynamics via c# code using simple.Odata.Client.

Comment: Are you able to test this library setup for any other entity like account or contact? Also you are using a template to create email, try to create task activity when the first attempt for account creation succeeds. Take small steps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not using some url like `/api/data/v8.0/activityparties` for creating activity entities. You should always target the individual activity type as `emails` or `tasks` or `phonecalls` like the endpoint `/api/data/v8.0/emails` since all the individual activities will create `activitypointers`, `activityparties` in the background. 
[Read more about complex "Activity" entity](https://crmbusiness.wordpress.com/2015/11/12/crm-2015-what-developers-need-to-know-about-the-activity-entity/)

You cannot create Activity party entity records directly as that entity only supports `RetrieveMultiple` message, but not `Create` or `Update`. [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/entities/activityparty)

**Sample code to create an Activity & set Activity Party**

```
///------------ Create Phone Call Activity ----------

function createPhoneCall() {
    try {
        //declare variables
        var phonecallId = null;
        var stringJSONPhone = null;
        var urlPhone = null;

        //create activity party collection
        var parties = [];

        //create JSON object 
        var JSONPhone = {};

        //set fields using JSON object
        //Single line of text
        JSONPhone["subject"] = "Test Phone Call"; //Subject

        //Single line of text & format of phone 
        JSONPhone["phonenumber"] = "9876543210"; //Phone Number

        //Multiple Line of Text
        JSONPhone["description"] = "Phone Call Activity for Testing Purpose only...!"; //Description

        //Date and Time
        JSONPhone["scheduledend"] = new Date(); //Due

        //Lookup
        JSONPhone["regardingobjectid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(B386D403-F7AD-E511-80DC-A45D36FC4F90)"; //Regarding is an account

        //ActivityParty (From)
        var sender = {};
        sender["partyid_systemuser@odata.bind"] = "/systemusers(D949B11D-9240-4037-8379-F31C7A36680E)";
        sender["participationtypemask"] = 1; //From

        //ActivityParty (To)
        var receiver1 = {};
        receiver1["partyid_account@odata.bind"] = "/accounts(B386D403-F7AD-E511-80DC-A45D36FC4F90)";
        receiver1["participationtypemask"] = 2; //To

        var receiver2 = {};
        receiver2["partyid_contact@odata.bind"] = "/contacts(DFE54660-37CD-E511-80DE-6C3BE5A831DC)";
        receiver2["participationtypemask"] = 2; //To

        var receiver3 = {};
        receiver3["partyid_lead@odata.bind"] = "/leads(ED81F0D9-37CD-E511-80DE-6C3BE5A831DC)";
        receiver3["participationtypemask"] = 2; //To

        //add this to collection
        parties.push(sender);
        parties.push(receiver1);
        parties.push(receiver2);
        parties.push(receiver3);

        //pass parties[] to phonecall_activity_parties
        JSONPhone["phonecall_activity_parties"] = parties;

        //Whole Number
        JSONPhone["actualdurationminutes"] = 25; //Duration

        //Two Options
        JSONPhone["directioncode"] = true;//Direction : 0-->False/Incoming, 1-->True/Outgoing

        //convert JSON object to string
        stringJSONPhone = JSON.stringify(JSONPhone);

        //url for ajax request to create phonecall activity
        urlPhone = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v8.0/phonecalls";

        //ajax request to create phonecall activity
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            url: urlPhone,
            data: stringJSONPhone,
            beforeSend: function (CreatePhoneCallActivityRequest) {
                CreatePhoneCallActivityRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                CreatePhoneCallActivityRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                CreatePhoneCallActivityRequest.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=*");
                CreatePhoneCallActivityRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
                CreatePhoneCallActivityRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
            },
            //Success Callback Function
            success: function (data, taxtStatus, getPhoneCallActivityResponse) {
                //get Response from Created Record
                phonecallId = getPhoneCallActivityResponse.getResponseHeader("OData-EntityId");

                //get EntityId from ResponseHeader of Created Record 
                phonecallId = phonecallId.split(/[()]/);
                phonecallId = phonecallId[1];

                //Display Enttity ID of Created Record
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Entity ID : " + phonecallId);

            },
            //Error Callback Function
            error: function (CreatePhoneCallActivityRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Something Wrong in Script...:(");
            }
        });
    } catch (e) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(e.message + "\n" + e.description);
    }
}
```

[Code reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/posts/set-values-of-all-data-types-using-web-api-in-dynamics-crm)